# How am I able to retrieve google.com page so fast?

Tags: networking, distributed-computing

When I type google.com in my browser, The page loads so fast in 1 sec.
When I do traceroute for google.com from my laptop terminal , then it takes couple of seconds(21 hops) to give me the location of server using 52 byte packet.

Can some one please explain me how come the data is flowing from india (my location) that fast to pull a page from server that is located in USA california.  what is the math/logic behind it.  If google has a datacenter in India( I think it is in mumbai) then why it did not connect to it and rather it went to USA california.